# How to run multiple test classes in testng suite with only one web driver instance?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have testng.xml file as below...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.cigital.myssi.automation.tests.SoftwareTest"/>         
      <class name="com.cigital.myssi.automation.tests.LoginTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

I have the corresponding test classes as below....

SoftwareTest.java

```
public class SoftwareTest extends Verification {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private SoftwarePage softwarepage;
    private LoginPage loginpage;
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(SoftwareTest.class);

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setup() throws InterruptedException {
        driver = DriverFactory.getDriverInstance();
        softwarepage = new SoftwarePage(driver);
        loginpage = new LoginPage(driver);
    }

    @Test(description="Create Critical Software")
    public void CreateCriticalProject()
    {
        log.info("Create Critical Software test case Started...............");
        assertEquals(true, loginpage.gotoSignPage());
        assertEquals(true,loginpage.LogintoPortal("abc@abc.com", "Pass@123", "Welcome"));
        assertEquals(true,softwarepage.CreateCriticalSoftware(DataGenerator.RandomNumber("SAMPLE")));
        assertEquals(true,loginpage.Logout());
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDown() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
}

}
```

LoginTest.java

```
public class LoginTest extends Verification {

    private WebDriver driver;
    private LoginPage loginPage;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setup() throws InterruptedException {
        driver = DriverFactory.getDriverInstance();
        loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
    }   

    @Test(description = "SigninPage")
    public void SigninPage() {
        assertEquals(true, loginPage.gotoSignPage());
    }

    @Test(description="Login to Portal",dependsOnMethods="SigninPage",dataProviderClass=CredentialsProvider.class,dataProvider="testCasesLogin")
    public void LoginToPortal(UserBean newbean) throws InterruptedException
    {
        assertEquals(true,loginPage.LogintoPortal(newbean.getUsername(),newbean.getPassword(),newbean.getTitle()));
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDown() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
}
}
```

I have initiated webdrive in both the classes. The problem is whenever the first test i.e. SoftwareTest is executed then the browser quits. But, I want to execute the next test i.e. LoginTest in order. Can anyone help me how can I achieve that?

Regards,

Comment: Hi..you can create before and after suite to start and quit the browser.. Only once if you are intended to the same..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below new class

```
public class Config extends Verification{

public static WebDriver driver;

public SoftwarePage softwarepage;
public LoginPage loginpage;

@BeforeSuite
public void setUp(){
    driver = DriverFactory.getDriverInstance();
}

@AfterSuite
public void tearDown(){

    if (driver != null) {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

}

extends this class to all other test classes some thing like below

```
public class SoftwareTest extends Config {

private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(SoftwareTest.class);

@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void setup() throws InterruptedException {

    softwarepage = new SoftwarePage(driver);

}
```

here no need of AfterClass i hope and also in BeforeClass delete this 'driver = DriverFactory.getDriverInstance();'

Let me know if you have any issues..

Thanks

Comment: also delete these private WebDriver driver; private SoftwarePage softwarepage; private LoginPage loginpage; in test classes..i hope you know these..

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a driver instance for both the classes in `BeforeClass` method, so once the class is executed `AfterClass` method is called and it is closing your driver.

Instead of using `BeforeClass` & `AfterClass` methods you can use `BeforeSuite` method to launch the browser and `AfterSuite` method to quit the driver. This would solve your purpose.

This `BeforeSuite` and `AfterSuite` method you can create in any of the 2 classes that you have created.

Comment: I have used replaced beforeclass and afterclass in softwaretest.java with beforesuite and aftersuite but again it is closing after the first test executed

Comment: Lokesh, create separate class for these before suite and after suite.. Extend this class to every other classes..let me know how it works

Comment: @murail, But I am already inheriting another class in each of test class file, so I cannot inherit any more...

Comment: cool yaar.. inherit previous one to this class which is created for beforesuite and after suite... inherit this suite class to all test classes..

Comment: as you can see in both the test classes I have initialized like this softwarepage = new SoftwarePage(driver); which would return the driver instance If I removed these from test classes, how can I call the methods in those respective page classes...

Comment: @Lokesh, please see answer just i posted..let me know if you have any issues there..